# Get text along with `.children` in texSoup

Tags: python, html, latex

I'm writing a Python program that'll convert LaTeX documents to HTML documents. I'm using the `tex-soup` package. Here's what I've currently got:

```py
import argparse

from TexSoup import TexSoup


class LaTeXtoHTML:
    def __init__(self, tex, note_type, note_number):
        self.tex = tex
        self.note_type = note_type
        self.note_number = note_number

        self.html = ""

        self.enivronments = [
            "definition",
            "theorem",
            "lemma",
            "example",
            "question",
            "solution",
            "remark",
            "purpleframe",
            "note",
            "problem",
            "corollary",
            "proposition",
            "conjecture",
            "explanation",
            "notation",
            "recall",
            "claim",
            "case",
            "acknowledgment",
            "conclusion",
        ]

    def convert_enumerate_itemize_to_html(self, environment, tag):
        """
        Convert LaTeX enumerate and itemize to HTML.

        Args:
            environment (TexSoup environment): LaTeX environment.
            tag (str): HTML tag.
        """

        body = ""
        for item in environment.children:
            if item.name == "item":
                item_content = str(item).replace("\\item", "").strip()
                item_content = self.convert_tex_to_html(item_content)
                body += f"<li>\n{item_content}\n</li>\n"

        html = f"<{tag}>\n{body}</{tag}>\n"

        return html

    def convert_figure_to_html(self, environment):
        """
        Convert LaTeX figure environment to HTML.

        Args:
            environment (TexSoup environment): LaTeX figure environment.
            environment_name (str): Name of the LaTeX environment (default:
                                                                   "figure").

        Returns:
            str: HTML representation of the figure environment.
        """
        # Extracting the caption
        caption = ""
        try:
            caption_element = environment.caption
            if caption_element:
                caption = caption_element.string
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        # Extracting the image or TikZ/PGF plot
        content = ""
        try:
            if environment.includegraphics:
                image_src = environment.includegraphics.args[0]
                content += f'<img src="{image_src}" alt="Figure" />\n'
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        try:
            if environment.tikzpicture:
                content += '<script type="text/tikz">'
                content += f"\n{environment.tikzpicture}\n</script>\n"
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        try:
            if environment.incfig:
                incfig_args = environment.incfig.args

                fig_name = ""
                scale = 1

                if len(incfig_args) == 1:
                    fig_name = str(incfig_args[0])
                else:
                    scale = int(incfig_args[0])
                    fig_name = str(incfig_args[1])

                fig_name = f"{fig_name[1:-1]}.pdf_tex"

                fig_path = f"figures/{self.note_type}-{self.note_number}/"
                fig_path += f"{fig_name}"

                content += f'<object data="{fig_path}" type="image/svg+xml" '
                content += f'width="{scale * 100}%" />\n'
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        # Combining the caption and content into HTML
        html = "<figure>"
        html += f"\n{content}"
        html += f"\n<figcaption>{caption}</figcaption>"
        html += "\n</figure>"

        return html

    def convert_environment_to_html(self, environment, environment_name=None):
        """
        Convert LaTeX environment to HTML. This is a recursive function,
        which calls itself to convert nested environments until it reaches
        the end of the environment.

        Args:
            environment (TexSoup environment): LaTeX environment.
            environment_name (str): Name of the LaTeX environment.
        """

        title = None
        try:
            title = environment.args[0].string
        except IndexError:
            title = None

        def_title = f', name="{title}"' if title else ""
        body = " ".join(str(child) for child in environment.contents[2:])

        html = "\n{{< " + str(environment_name) + def_title + " >}}\n"
        html += self.convert_tex_to_html(body)
        html += "{{< /" + str(environment_name) + " >}}\n"

        return html

    def convert_tex_to_html(self, tex):
        """
        Convert LaTeX to HTML.

        Args:
            tex (str): LaTeX string.

        Returns:
            str: HTML string.
        """

        tex_soup = TexSoup(tex)
        html = ""

        for element in tex_soup.children:
            if element.name == "section":
                html += f"<h2>{element.string}</h2>\n\n"
            elif element.name == "subsection":
                html += f"<h3>{element.string}</h3>\n\n"
            elif element.name == "subsubsection":
                html += f"<h4>{element.string}</h4>\n\n"
            elif element.name == "paragraph":
                html += f"<h5>{element.string}</h5>\n\n"
            elif element.name == "subparagraph":
                html += f"<h6>{element.string}</h6>\n\n"
            elif element.name in self.enivronments:
                html += self.convert_environment_to_html(element, element.name)
            elif element.name in ["enumerate", "itemize"]:
                tag = "ul" if element.name == "itemize" else "ol"
                html += self.convert_enumerate_itemize_to_html(element, tag)
            elif element.name == "figure":
                html += self.convert_figure_to_html(element)
            else:
                html += str(element) + "\n"

        return html


def main():
    """Main function."""

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Convert LaTeX files to HTML files.",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-i", "--input", type=str, help="Input LaTeX file", required=True
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-o", "--output", type=str, help="Output HTML file", required=True
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with open(args.input, "r") as f:
        tex = f.read()
        if "lec" in args.input:
            note_type = "lec"
        else:
            note_type = "chap"

        note_number = args.input.split("-")[-1].split(".")[0]
        latex_to_html = LaTeXtoHTML(tex, note_type, note_number)

        converted = latex_to_html.convert_tex_to_html(tex)
        print(converted)

        # with open(args.output, "w") as f:
        #     f.write(converted)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's the testing file I'm using:

```tex
\section{Hi}

This is some text in a section.

\begin{definition}[Definition name]
  \label{def:definition_name}

  This is a definition.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1
  \end{enumerate}
\end{definition}
```

When running the program with `python3 main.py -i lec-02.tex -o lec-02.html`, I get:

```html
<h2>Hi</h2>


{{< definition, name="Definition name" >}}
<ol>
<li>

</li>
</ol>
{{< /definition >}}
```

I cannot seem to get just the regular text. I only get environments or commands from `.children`. I don't know how to get the regular text (which, in this case, is `This is some text in a section.`, `This is a definition.`, and `Item 1`). I need to use `.children`, as I can parse based on names, as opposed to `.contents`, which doesn't have that and only lists them as strings.